# what is the best way to implement multiple log location in portlet factory project?

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal

I have to implement log4j for 7 modules(each module includes several models)in my IBM Web Experience Factory (formerly known as portlet factory) project. for each module I should implement the separate log location.  How can I configure the log locations?

Comment: What? I have no idea what you're talking about.. What is IBM? Does that thing still exist? why is this tagged WPF? What is your question?? Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Web Experience Factory  (WEF) (formerly named WebSphere Portlet Factory and sometimes formerly referred to as wpf, but MS and most developers use that acronym to mean something else) shouldn't be tagged as wpf on SO, since that tag is specific to the MS wpf.   If you could update your posting, I suggest removing that wpf tag (there is a WebSphere Portal tag that you could use, but not yet a tag specific to Web Experience Factory).

I'm not sure what you mean by "modules"  (portlets?  portlet WAR?), but each Portlet WAR will have it's own WEF log location (by default located under WEB-INF/logs in the deployed WAR) configured by WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties (in the project and then in the deployed WAR).   I suggest searching for logging and log4j in the WEF documentation and WEF Wiki (URL in my signature below) and also on the Web Experience Factory forum (URL also below) for more info on customizing the logging.

IBM Web Experience Factory (WEF - formerly WebSphere Portlet Factory and sometimes also formerly called WPF) Forum: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000889

I hope that info helps,
..Mike Burati 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/
The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM.